# Efficient routines for a regression with orthogonal regressors?

Tags: r, regression, algorithms, matrix-inverse

I have a standard OLS regression setup, where (sets of) the regresors are orthogonal to each other. I am looking for a fast low-level way (using `qr()` instead of `lm()` ) to do this in R. So far, I can think of at least three approaches:

1. **Simple:** Run the standard OLS: should be slow as does not make use of the orthogonal structure
2. **Separate:** Run regressions separately: we know that with orthogonal regressors, we could get the same estimates by estimating OLS on each (sets of ) regressors separately.
3. **Sparse:** Use a sparse routine:  the X matrix contains many zeros, so could be considered sparse. Or use a "block diagonal" routine in R for inverting the $X^\prime X$ noting that with (sets of ) orthogonal regressors, it is (block) diagonal.

Against my expectations, in a single experiment (code below) I ran, the simplest method (1, simple) was the fastest, while the fancy sparse method the slowest.  Any ideas of why this would happen? Any idea of a better way/different routines that make use of the block-diagonal structure?

Thanks!

```
library(Matrix)
library(microbenchmark)


n <- 1000
k <- 5
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol=k)
eps <- rnorm(n)
y <- as.matrix(ifelse(1:n<(n/2), 
                  x %*% seq(0.8, by=0.05,length.out=k)+eps, 
                  x %*% seq(0.5, by=0.05,length.out=k)+eps))


X_s <- bdiag(x[1:(n/2),], x[(n/2+1):n,])
X <- as.matrix(X_s)
microbenchmark(Simple=qr.coef(qr(X), y),
           Separate=c(qr.coef(qr(X[,1]), y), qr.coef(qr(X[,2]), y)),
           Sparse=qr.coef(qr(X_s), y))
```

Comment: Which BLAS do you use? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665403/r-detection-of-blas-version) for details.

Comment: Also, just to state the obvious: a matrix with 50% zero entries does not count as "sparse" numerically. I would not expect a sparse method to be competitive to a dense method unless the zero entries where at least around the 85%-90% of the matrix. The huge speed-ups that are sometimes reported commonly concern matrices with sub 5% non-zero entries. And to save an allocation try `qr.solve( X, y)` instead of `qr.coef(qr(X), y)` marginally faster in the dense case, quite faster in the sparse.

Comment: At $n = 1000$ and  $k = 2$ ($k$ is the number of predictors), you are *far* from testing the efficiencies of these methods. You might want to try again with something like $n = 100,000$ and $k = 100$ to start getting a feel for computational costs. Note that the computational complexity of linear regression is $O(nk^2)$ using basic methods.

Comment: Regarding of the BLAS, the code is intended for a package, so I was abstracting from that! Also, the typical application I have is n=500, or 1000, and k=5, so maybe I won't be able to "start feeling the computational costs"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, unless you $k$ is substantially bigger than $5$ you will observe almost no difference. In light of this, I think `qr.solve` is your best bet. Avoid over-engineered solutions unless they offer obvious advantages; they are harder to use, maintain and/or explain.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the sparse method is so much slower is that you are using a rather dense matrix as a sparse matrix. 50% non-zero elements are just too many for a matrix to be considered sparse. You really should aim for ~5% so you can enjoy obvious and consistent speed-ups. In general, I would not expect a sparse method to be competitive to a dense method unless the zero entries were at least around the 85%-90% of the matrix.

Having said that what you do is correct to use QR. I would suggest using `qr.solve` directly so I save one extra assignment but other than that you are using the standard way to solve the normal equations.
If you really want to be aggressive, try to use [Cholesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $LL^T$ decomposition. Using the triangular matrix $L$ you can [back/forwardsolve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution) the system at hand. This is a very fast operation. So something like in R:

```
cholCoef <- function(X,y){
              U <- chol(crossprod(X)); 
              backsolve( U, backsolve( transpose=TRUE, U, x= crossprod(X,y))) 
            }
```

Please note that this can be numerically unstable and fail horribly if the matrix `crossprod(X)` is not positive definite or the condition number associated with $X$ is already high but hey... we want speed no stability. Generally speaking the Cholesky's complexity is of the order $\frac{1}{3} n^3$ FLOPS while QR's complexity is of the order  $\frac{4}{3} n^3$. (See Trefethen & Bau, 1997 [Numerical linear algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713617) for more details).

Finally it worth noting that the package [RcppEigen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/index.html) has `fastLM` function you may want to consider. The argument `method` defines the actual algorithm to use. Probably the `fastLM( ...,  method = 2)` is good enough to almost general use. It will do an $LDL^T$ decomposition instead of the standard Cholesky: $LL^T$ so it rather stable. In my system `CholSolve` is the fastest using the following microbenchmark.

```
microbenchmark( 
  Simple= qr.solve(X, y), 
  CholSolve = cholCoef( X = X, y),  
  Separate=c(qr.coef(qr(X[,1]), y), qr.coef(qr(X[,2]), y)), 
  Sparse=qr.coef(qr(X_s), y),  
  FastLM = fastLm(X,y, method= 2L))
```

As mentioned by @Cliff the matrices you deal with are rather small so you would probably want to use something bigger to evaluate the differences between different algorithms' numerical performance. Finally note that the [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) variant use by your R installation will make a very big difference. I would strongly urge you to use [OpenBLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBLAS) or [ATLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software) if you are not using them already. (See my comment to check which BLAS you use.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I note however that the Choleski or the fastLM routines you suggest do not make use of the orthogonal structure of the regressors? I was wondering if in particular there is a way to use this to get faster results?  I tried using the Choleski on each sub-block separately, but did not get faster results...

Comment: I am glad I could help. The fact you have orthogonal predictors means that you can use `sqrt` directly instead of `chol`. That is because you know that the off-diagonal elements of $X^TX$ are zero. Aside that the forward/backwards procedure is the same; theoretically the b/fsolve could be parallelized now but unless you have a massive system ($k$ to the thousands) to solve no benefits would be seen. In my system `sqrtCoef` (the same as `cholCoef` just replacing `chol` with `sqrt`) is even faster than `cholCoef` but really you do not gain much.